# OutOfMemoryError Exception in hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, out-of-memory

I have a OutOfMemoryError when i run my springBoot application ,

```
@Transaction(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) 
void public function() {
   subFunction() ;
}
```

Subfunction process file with 3000000 lines and create insert query to dataBase.
The program aborted in line 1900000 with outOfMemory error.

When we analyze dump with Eclipse Memory analyzer we have that result :
[image]

Any help will be useful , thank you .

Comment: Please use the search as questions regarding batch inserting with JPA/Hibernate have been answered before.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate keeps all entities that you persist in the persistence context. If you do not need these entities anymore, you can flush and clear them out in e.g. batches of 50 items.

```
int lineCount = 0;
for (String line : lines) {
  // Your code
  entityManager.persist(entity);
  lineCount++;
  if ((lineCount % 50) == 0) {
      entityManager.flush();
      entityManager.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,I try this but it didn't solve the problem,i will add that i use nativeQuery to insert in DB.

Comment: @ Christian Beikov Thanks ,I try this but it didn't solve the problem,i will add that i use nativeQuery to insert in DB.